# CMS not accessible on home server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, magento, cms

I've setup a server at home with Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS to develop and experiment on for our Magento webshop. The server itself runs fine when contacted from the internal network. 
I got magento to load under 1s so everything runs fine.

However now i switch a lot between locations and would like to keep to work on the installation form an external point.

When i call the server by IP nothing loads... when i remove the CMS and place a static HTML page it loads fine. However when i put the CMS (magento store in this case) back  and try to reach it nothing works.

I had Apache2 configured to listen to 2417 instead of 80 (my router blocks it), and setup a port forward.

After some googling i cannot come up with a solution and hope you guys can steer me in the right direction :)

If i have left out needed information please ask and i'll fill in (Kind of new to the external home server setup... )

UPDATE:
I've just performed a clean install to start from scratch, Apache2 has been configured to listen to 2417.

Firewal is inactive

Do i need to set other components like MySQL to listen to another port also to make te CMS accessible from the outside?

Thanks in advance!
Kind regards,
NIck

Comment: Looks like the CMS itself may have a config that prevents connections from outside the local network. What's the name of the CMS? Magento Store? our Magento webshop? ...

Comment: Magento is an e-commerce platform [Magento](https://magento.com/)

Comment: Can you include your virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinkering around i've found the solution:

Setting:
curl --max-time [seconds] --connect-timeout [seconds] http://yoururl.com/ to a longer time limit has resolved the issue.

I found out that libcurl gave a connection-timedout at 2000 miliseconds.